# A sufficient condition that grants a group is finite

Tags: group-theory

We have to prove this statement:
Let $H,K$ finite subgroups of a group $G$, suppose $H$ is is subnormal, then $\langle H,K \rangle $is finite.
The trivial case occurs when $H$ is a normal subgroup, then $HK$ is the group we are searching for and we conclude by cardinality.

Comment: Have you tried induction?...

Comment: Choose $H \le N \lhd G$ so that the subnormal depth of $H$ is $N$ is less than in $G$. Now $H$ has finitely many conjugates under $K$ so by induction they generate a finite subgroup $L$ of $N$ and now $\langle H,K\rangle \le LK$ is finite.